# disallow some domain names, allow others

Tags: regex

For example there are URLs **http://www.subdomain1.domain.com.uk** and **http://www.subdomain2.domain.uk**, from these URLs I need to extract only the name *subdomain1* or *subdomain2*.

But if I receive **http://www.subdomain3.co.uk** or **http://www.subdomain4.com** I need to get the whole URL like *subdomain3.co.uk* or *subdomain4.com*.

My expression: `^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?((?!SubdomainToNegate|www).*)((?!\.domain\.com\.uk|\.domain\.uk).*)$`

Expression catches whole URL.

My situation is shown better over there: http://www.rubular.com/r/B1iOUoUq33

Comment: Probably a typo, but I should point out that `.com.uk` is not a valid UK domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found solution:

```
http:\/\/(?:www\.)?((?:(?!domain.com.uk|domain.uk)[^\s.]+)(?:\.(?!domain.com.uk|domain.uk)[^\s.]+)*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?((?!SubdomainToNegate|www)[^\.]*)((?!\.domain\.com\.uk|\.domain\.uk).*)$
```

difference is this

```
(?!SubdomainToNegate|www)[^\.]*
```

instead of this

```
(?!SubdomainToNegate|www)\.*
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a little bit. I've rewritten my expression to this: ^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?((?!SubdomainToNegate|www)[^\.]*\.(?!domain\.com\.uk|domain\.uk).*)$ but the results are not as I expected.  http://www.rubular.com/r/qAdMdJoNYb